# How to use ArgumentCaptor to verify bytes written to HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, mockito

I have a controller that provides functionality to download the file.

```
@ResponseBody
public void downloadRecycleResults(String batchName, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    File finalResultFile = null;
    // code here generates and initializes finalResultFile for batchName
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + finalResultFile.getName());
    IOUtils.copy(new FileReader(finalResultFile), response.getOutputStream());
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to write test where I can verify the contents which were written to `response`. I have used `ArgumentCaptor` lot but somehow it doesn't seem to fit here.

```
controller.downloadRecycleResults("batchName", mock(HttpServletResponse.class));
verify(response).getOutputStream(); // but how to capture content?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to mock both `response` and its output stream, then verify calls to the `write` method of your mocked output stream.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I thought of that too right after posting. I'll post code as answer in case anyone stumbles upon.

Answer (score 17):

As suggested by David, I was able to do so.

```
ServletOutputStream opStreamMock = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);
when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(opStreamMock);

ArgumentCaptor<byte[]> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(byte[].class);
verify(opStreamMock).write(captor.capture(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt());

//can create reader now.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(captor.getValue())));
```