# Count actual bytes written to tomcat HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to count the actual bytes written to a HttpServletResponse to make sure that the whole file has been transfered. My naive approach is like this:

```
            InputStream instream = InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("myfile.zip");
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = res.getOutputStream();

            CountingInputStream countingInputStream = new CountingInputStream(instream);
            IOUtils.copy(countingInputStream, outputStream);

            log.debug("Expected count: " + String.valueOf(contentLength));
            log.debug("getCount: " + countingInputStream.getCount());

            outputStream.close();
            countingInputStream.close();
            instream.close();
```

While this approach works well on Jetty, Tomcat returns always the full outputstream to be written, even if the client has canceled the download.

Futhermore this has also worked well for years on Tomcat 6. We now had to migrate to Tomcat 7 and experienced this issue.

Is there a way to count the bytes that have been actually sent to the client?

Comment: Try `byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);`

Comment: It could be possible that Tomcat 7 (or some other server in between) is buffering the output before sending it to the client

Comment: @Suzon This would cause the stream to be buffered in the byte[]. We are transfering files of 2GB. So this would not perform very well if it would work at all.

Comment: @JoseM In fact I suspect Tomcat to buffer the stream but I am not quite sure. Futhermore I don't know how to work around this issue.

Comment: Here is good example [How to use ArgumentCaptor to verify bytes written to HttpServletResponse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445165/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-to-verify-bytes-written-to-httpservletresponse)

Comment: @Suzon Thank you, but this is basically what I am already doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you have to investigate:

1. Is the content length header provided? If not, tomcat will cache the entire response
2. Make sure the container is configured to support chunked encoding.
3. Make sure the client supports chunked encoding (it is not HTTP 1.0)

Another thing is that the tomcat streaming infrastructure suffered a major refactoring with the websockets implementation after version 7.0.27. For more details, take a look here:

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/05/01/how-apache-tomcat-implemented-websocket

Comment: The content length is properly set and both, client and server are supporting chunked encoding.